# Reading integers from text file in c# and writing them into array

Tags: c#, image, file, integer, pixel

I'm trying to read the values of pixels from text file and generate an image file. But first I want to make sure that I can read all of the values in the file. I use this code, but the output misses some of the integers from the input file-the last ones. I don't know why! Can you help me? Here's the code:

```
namespace txtToImg
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("D:\\out.txt");
            string fileContent = File.ReadAllText("D:\\in.txt");

            string[] integerStrings = fileContent.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            int[] integers = new int[integerStrings.Length];
            //tw.Write(integerStrings.Length);

            for (int n = 0; n < integerStrings.Length; n++)
            {
                integers[n] = int.Parse(integerStrings[n]);

                tw.Write(integers[n]+" ");


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice the StreamWriter object doesn't appear to be getting closed. Not sure if that would make any difference, but its the only obvious thing I can see.

Comment: You sure that shouldn't be `fileContent.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\n' }, ...` ?

Comment: My integers are split by space, I don't need '\n' or ','. Thanks though!

Comment: Andrew, Thank you so much! I closed the StreamWriter object tw and it worked! I do not know why, but it works perfectly now! Thank you again!

Comment: @AnaZlateva The best way is to use `using` as in Bearcat's suggestion below. Then it will get closed automatically, even if an exception occurs.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean for Image file, but do you know that a TextWriter, writes character in the output file?. You can't create an image with this code.

Comment: My guess is hes just outputting to a file for now to verify collection of data from the source. But you are correct this code will not generate a image.

Comment: calling `Close()/Dispose()` on the TextWriter forces the class to flush it's buffer. the reason you weren't seeing output was probably because you weren't filling the buffer enough during program execution to force it to automatically flush.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to verify if I have all the pixels in the array already. And now the next step is to try to create an image and set the pixels to the values I already have in the array. If anyone has done that before or have an idea, I'd be thankful to see what you think!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Andrew's comment your streamWriter object isn't getting closed so for one thing I would try this.  I made the change below and attempted what you are doing and my output file contained all the entries.

```
 using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\out.txt"))
        {
            string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\in.txt");

            string[] integerStrings = fileContent.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            int[] integers = new int[integerStrings.Length];

            for (int n = 0; n < integerStrings.Length; n++)
            {
                integers[n] = int.Parse(integerStrings[n]);
                tw.Write(integers[n] + " ");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ana if this answer has solved your problem , don't forget to choose it as your question's answer

Answer (score 0):

Right, I've just ran it and as I suspected you need the following after your loop:

```
tw.Close();
```

Comment: Like Andrew suggested I would wrap  your TextWriter in a using statement.  It Implements IDiposable so after the closing brace tw is properly disposed, and your out file then is release and accessible to other processes.